# Should I worry about PHP injection if I don't use MySQL?

Tags: php

I use a simple PHP script to run an online comic which basically uses a GET to take an integer value *n* and insert an img tag for *n*.jpg. It doesn't do any sanitizing or error checking beyond making sure that *n*.jpg exists. The only user interaction with the script is through this GET, and another that does the same thing with a string to manually display a different template for testing.

My question is, should I even be worrying about injection? And if so, what should I do to prevent it? Everything I've found so far only concerns MySQL injection, which doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: PHP can use other databases than MySQL, and code injection can be done with any (?) SQL database, or any code evaluating external input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not using a database, then obviously SQL injection is not a concern for your. Similarly, if you don't store any user-submitted data to display to other users, [Cross-site-scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is not a concern. That leaves stuff like `eval()` or running external processes, which an attacker could subvert, but it doesn't sound like you do anything like that either.

So you're probably safe. Still, it would be good to have a minimum amount of error checking, just to get into the habit. For example, you say that you have an integer GET parameter. There's no such thing - all HTTP parameters are implicity strings. PHP blurs the distinction, but you definitely should cast it to int explicitly to make sure it's not some string intended to exploit an XSS, SQL injection or eval vulnerability (even if none such exist).

Comment: Since the parameter is part of a filename it's really just a string consisting of numbers. And because the existance of said file is checked, casting would be superfluous. But normally it would be a good idea. As pointed out in an answer below, `ctype_digit` should suffice to ensure valid input.

Comment: @nikc the point is that you cannot prevent someone from submitting a request containing arbitrarily manipulated parameter values, so you generally must not make any assumptions what form parameters can take.

Comment: XSS is still a concern, even if you're not storing data and showing to it others. look at the section "Non-persistent" in the wikipedia page you linked to

Answer (score 3):

You should always worry about security. Not every security hole is made up by the wrong usage of mysql :-)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL injection is not applicable in your case because you are not using a database for your site. But you should consider other security issues for your site too such as [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

If you are using a variable from GET, consider below url:

```
 index.php?myvar=<script>alert(document.cookie);</script>
```

The hackers are able to provide above url in a number ways hex, utf, etc.

A bad guy can modify your GET variables to perform XSS attacks. XSS is the root of many security holes. You need to consider that too.

If you are expecting a numeric type from your GET var then consider below code:

```
$myvar = (int) $_GET['your_var'];
```

You should use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to prevent the XSS attacks.

Comment: Note that XSS is irrelevant when the possibly malicious input is merely used to construct a page to display to the same user. XSS is only a problem when the input from one user is shown to others.

Comment: @Michael: "XSS is only a problem when the input from one user is shown to others". Wouldn't it be possible to fool another user into clicking a malicious link which contains some HTML to inject? Then the injected javascript etc. runs in their browser as them.

Comment: Competely agree with Tom Haigh. It is easy to fool others into clicking your link. If they have an account at the site, and the link allows injection of XSS, be it non-persistent, then you can execute grab the contents of the page and send it to your server, or call functions exposed by the page which will execute as if they were executed at the user's request.

Why allow XSS if you can prevent it?

Comment: @Tom, Roland: if you can fool a user into clicking a malicious link, what do you need the "vulnerable" page for? You could make it a javascript: URL right away. I guess the detour via the page could serve to disguise the javascript though.

Comment: @michael: the vulnerable page allows the malicious user to execute javascript in the same domain as the page itself, so can therefore access and steal cookies it has set etc.

Answer (score 1):

If get is supposed to only contain an integer use

`$n = intval($_GET['n'])`

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting a number, don't sanitize bad input, deny it.

```
if ( !ctype_digit($user_input) ) {
    header('Location: error.php'); // or whatever page
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Or just force it: `printf("%u", $_GET['n']);`

Comment: I guess it's personal taste. I never allow a bad request by correcting it: if it's bad it must generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

Allways check user input and $_GET and $_POST data for malicious content. Addslashes, ereg_match and intval are your friend...

If you can get away with it, set the

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

directive in php.ini

Comment: Should this directive not be disabled instead...?

Answer (score 0):

I'd also requests hit your desired images directory too, as you don't want people browsing your file server with requests like `example.com/?q=../../.htaccess`

I'm not sure how that would affect the output, but it can't be good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about SQL injection. But you should check your input as it is used in the html you generate.
Imagine I give this link `http://www.example.com/viewComic.php?id="/><script type="text/javascript>alert("XSS");</script><img src="22` to someone. This person will have a little pop-up coming from your website. And a lot of bad things can be done with javascript.
For more infos, you can start reading the wikipedia page about [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

So, you should check that the number you expect is a number. For example with [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).